# React app page routing issue post successful user login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-context, use-reducer

I have a react app where I use the `useContext` and `useReducer` hooks for the login and storage. While the login part works, what I want achieve is to redirect user to a specific page post successful login. I am using `react-router@6` and tried to use `useNavigate()` to navigate user to particular route though it doesn't seem to work.

```js
const AuthService = async (dispatch) => {
  
  const MSAL_CONFIG = {} // populate MSAL config for Microsoft Graph API for AD auth

  const msalInstance = new msal.PublicClientApplication(MSAL_CONFIG);

  try {
    const loginResponse = await msalInstance.loginPopup(scopes);
    var username = loginResponse.account.username;
    var userid = username.slice(0, username.indexOf("@"));

    const loginData = {
      auth_token: loginResponse.idToken,
      user: {
        name: loginResponse.account.name,
        id: userid,
        email: username,
      },
    };

    const sessionData = {
      user_id: userid,
      id_token: loginResponse.idToken,
      access_token: loginResponse.accessToken,
    }
 
    sessionStorage.setItem("currentUser", JSON.stringify(loginData));
    dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", payload: loginData });
    
    return { loginData: loginData, error: null };
    // dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS', payload: loginData });
    //sessionStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(data));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("+++ Login error : ", err);
    dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_ERROR", error: err });
    return { loginData: null, error: err };
  }
};
```

In my `header.jsx`, I have below code to handle the login button. It makes a call to the above `AuthService`. The code post `AuthService()` call, i.e. the if block, doesn't take effect, so user never gets redirected to the dashboard page.

```js
const handleLogin = async () => {
  await AuthService(dispatch) 
  console.log("userDetails.token : " + userDetails.token)
  if (Boolean(userDetails.token)) {
    navigate("/dashboard");
  } 
};
```

Comment: Thanks Drew. Apologies.. I should've put the code which sets the userDetails in the above JSX.. below lines are in the header jsx... const dispatch = useAuthDispatch();
  const userDetails = useAuthState(); at the start of the function component variable declaration section

Comment: and useAuthState() is a part of the authService.jsx... see below.........................import React, { useReducer } from "react";
  import { initialState, AuthReducer } from "./reducer";

  const AuthStateContext = React.createContext({});
  const AuthDispatchContext = React.createContext({});

  export const useAuthState = () => {
    const context = React.useContext(AuthStateContext);
    if (context === undefined) {
      throw new Error("useAuthState must be used within a AuthProvider");
    }

    return context;
  };

Comment: I see, that certainly explains why `dispatch` is passed to the `AuthService` function since it's not a Redux thunk/asynchronous action creator. Can you [edit] the code in those comments into the post for future readability?

Comment: correct, I already mentioned that in my original post i.e. I use useContext and useReducer hooks. NOT Redux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm correct in understanding that this `AuthService` function eventually resolves and that the dispatched `LOGIN_SUCCESS` action updates the `userDetails` variable that is selected from the auth context state, then I think you  have all that you need and are close to a working solution. The issue is that the `userDetails` value from the render cycle the `handleLogin` is called in is closed over in callback scope, it will never be a different value. If the `userDetails.token` value is falsey when `handleLogin` is called, it will remain falsey in the entire callback scope.

The `AuthService` function appears to return the same `loginData` object that is passed in the dispatched `LOGIN_SUCCESS` action to the store. `handleLogin` should `await` this value and conditionally navigate.

```js
const AuthService = async (dispatch) => {
  ...

  try {
    const { account, idToken } = await msalInstance.loginPopup(scopes);
    const { name, username } = account;
    const userid = username.slice(0, username.indexOf("@"));

    const loginData = {
      auth_token: idToken,
      user: {
        name,
        id: userid,
        email: username,
      },
    };

    ...
    
    sessionStorage.setItem("currentUser", JSON.stringify(loginData));
    dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", payload: loginData });
    
    return { loginData, error: null }; // <-- return value
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_ERROR", error });
    return { loginData: null, error }; // <-- return value
  }
};
```

```js
const handleLogin = async () => {
  const { loginData } = await AuthService(dispatch);

  if (loginData && loginData.auth_token) { // or loginData?.auth_token
    navigate("/dashboard", { replace: true });
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi Drew, After I've changed handleLogin code as per your suggestion, I got below error ....Failed to compile
./src/components/ui/header/header.component.jsx 152:26
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (152:26)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|             loginData = _yield$AuthService.loginData;
|             console.log(" loginData.token : " + loginData.token);
>             if (loginData?.auth_token) {
|               navigate("/dashboard", {
|                 replace: true

Comment: when I changed the handleLogin() code as per below, it worked ... I am still confused. Do you know why this works but any checks using the '?' operator on variable results in Babel error (see above comment)........       const handleLogin = async () => {
     await AuthService(dispatch) 
    if (userDetails) { 
      navigate("/dashboard", { replace: true });
    }
  };

Comment: @Dev Is your project not configured to use the [Optional Chaining Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)? If not then you can use the older null-check/guard-clause pattern. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks Drew. It's a long story though in a nutshell the amount of issues I've faced with React 18 due to pollyfills was just enormous. It was really disappointing breaking changes react-scripts brought.